# How far do ziplines go?

Tags: make-no-wonder

In [Make No Wonder](http://www.matthewhollett.com/wonder/index.php), ziplines say they let you connect to nearby platforms. How nearby do they need to be?

Comment: Hi! I made Make No Wonder. Thanks for playing! I left some notes on the answers below. I'd be happy to answer any other questions you have about the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only require line of sight between both towers in order to get a zipline between them. I suggest placing camps around your ziplines so you have more vision, even though platforms do provide a good range.

Note that you cannot move while placing ziplines, so beyond vision you are only limited by the size of the game window:

[image: zipline]

If you look where I'm standing in the center of the picture I couldn't have walked up any higher to place the zipline on the tower below me. I barely stretched it to the zipline above me from where I placed it.

Comment: Hi! I made Make No Wonder and this is the correct answer. Note that this means that you have a small advantage when playing the game with a larger view window (you can adjust the view window in the top right corner). This is more or less intentional (it isn't ideal, but I haven't found a better way to set it up).

Comment: Also, building camps does not affect your ability to place ziplines at all.

Comment: @shipshape Do you mean that you can build a zipline through fog of war, or that ziplines don't require camps to be built? What I meant is that camps clear a large area of fog, making it easier to have clear vision from one platform to another. If you look at http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/93686/1721 building a zipline through fog doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @shipshape Also very cool that you made the game! I know some people have said you need to add more to it but I don't think you need to. Right now it has lots of a-ha! moments and feels like an adventure game more than a sandbox game, which is cool. Maybe the game needs more solid closure, but the ending as-is works pretty well.

Comment: Yes, you can build ziplines through fog. Ziplines don't require camps, they just require platforms to be attached to. Make No Wonder is definitely more of an exploration / adventure game, I wouldn't call it a sandbox game. I have a lot of stuff I'd still like to add to it, I'm just busy with other stuff right now! Glad you're enjoying it!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be two towers that overlap in their vision. I haven't found anyplace to test exactly if that's it exactly, but [this works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Itkx6.png), and [this doesn't](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l91fI.png).

Comment: Hi! Your second situation doesn't work because you are standing too far away from the first platform to attach a zipline to it. If you were closer to one of the platforms and the view window was big enough it would work.